# How can I access rails_config keys at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a configuration like

```
foo:
  bar:
    - 1
    - 2
  baz:
    - 1
    - 2
```

How can I get an array containing `bar` and `baz`?

I tried

```
Settings.foo.keys
```

but this is `nil`, and it seems to be a `RailsConfig::Options` type.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to convert the configuration to a Hash:

```
Settings.foo.to_hash.keys
=> [:bar, :baz]
```

Note that these are given as symbols, so an `include? "bar"` won't work. `include? "bar".to_sym` however would. Or you could convert the symbols to strings after getting them from the hash.